# Postgres segmentation fault ruby gem

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rspec, segmentation-fault, rails-postgresql

I am trying to run this project https://github.com/eLobato/cartodb-rb-client but apparently either my rvm is messed up or pg has a terrible bug.
This is the error trace

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -S bundle exec rspec "./spec/model/data_spec.rb" "./spec/model/metadata_spec.rb" "./spec/model/scopes_spec.rb" "./spec/client_spec.rb"
/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cartodb-rb-client/gems/pg-0.11.0/lib/pg_ext.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

Aborted
rake aborted!
ruby -S bundle exec rspec "./spec/model/data_spec.rb" "./spec/model/metadata_spec.rb" "./spec/model/scopes_spec.rb" "./spec/client_spec.rb" failed

Tasks: TOP => spec
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The Segmentation fault line really bugs me a lot because I tried to reinstall pg with no avail. I am running Ubuntu 11.10 and I have installed both ruby 1.9.2 and 1.8.7

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

I had this error too. Fixed it by removing all versions of Ruby installed on my system, then re-installing 1.9.3

Like so:

`$ rvm remove all`

`$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392`

Answer (score 0):

You're running a system Ruby 1.8.7 interpreter, but somehow loading a `pg` gem installed under Ruby 1.9.2 installed via rvm.

Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 have substantially different ABIs, so their extensions are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

For me it seemed to be the version of the pg gem that was in my Gemfile.lock.  I had 0.13.2 in there, and it just didn't seem to work on Ruby 1.9.3.  I ran `bundle update pg` and got 0.14.0, and then things started working.

Answer (score -1):

Segmentation fault is, when program is accessing memory, which kernel don't expect (out of index, out of memory allocated block etc.).

What do you see, when you try:

```
ruby -S bundle --trace exec rspec "./spec/model/data_spec.rb" "./spec/model/metadata_spec.rb" "./spec/model/scopes_spec.rb" "./spec/client_spec.rb"
```

as backtrace advice to you?

Comment: <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- bundler (LoadError)
 from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
 from /usr/bin/bundle:4:in `<main>'

Comment: It seems, that there is problem in loading some required library from ruby. Did you compile ruby on this machine, or install it from Ubuntu repository or compile on another machine and only copy'ed to this machine?

Comment: Second view - have you installed ruby part 'bundler'? It seems to be a part, on which ruby complained about...